# MIN function in Excel

Tags: excel, minimum

I need to find minimums in a list of companies and prices. For example in one column I have apples, pears and grapes. For each of these there are several sellers and each of them has a different price. The list in the A coulmn would be Apple, Apple, Apple, Grapes, Grapes, Pear, Pear, Pear, Pear. In B would be Target, Trader Joe's, Harris Teeter etc... And in column C would be the price. Fruits in column A are in alphabetical order. I need to find a separate minimum for every fruit. I can do that manually except I have thousands of rows of data.

I'm thinking along the lines that I need to specify the area in which I want to return the minimum from. That would be as long as the entity in column A is the same, that's the area.

Does anyone know a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data starts at row 2 (headers in row 1) try this formula in D2 copied down

`=IF(A2=A1,"",MIN(OFFSET(C2,0,0,COUNTIF(A:A,A2))))`

That will give you the minimum price on the first row of each fruit. Filter column D on non-blanks to see just the minimums

Comment: Thank you! That's excactly what I needed!

Comment: Actually, in the D column I need the minimum in every row. So if the cheapest pear is 1 dollar, I need the D column in every row of pears say "1". Even if another store sells it for 2, I need column D of that row say "1".

Comment: Found the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of IF and MIN

```
=MIN( IF ( logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false ) )
```

e.g.

```
=MIN( IF ( A2:A100="Apple", B2:B100, 0 ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PivotTables:

1. Select your data and insert a PivotTable:

   [image]
2. Choose a location to put it. I'll put it in the same sheet:

   [image]
3. Click, drag and drop the fruits under Row Label and the Price under Row Values:

   [image]
4. Right click on the PivotTable and pick Summarise by > Minimum:

   [image]

And you should end up with this:

[image]

Comment: Found another answer but thank you for yours anyway!

Comment: @user3432836 As long as you have solved your problem, don't worry :) I always try to use PivotTables where possbile. It's a powerful tool of Excel that doesn't need much to learn so someone can use it, and you don't have to remember functions to carry out basic tasks!

Comment: Yes, pivot tables are great but not what I can use for my particular table. I simplified my table greatly for the purpose of the question.

Comment: @user3432836 Ahh, I see :) You should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) Barry's answer then. It'll indicate that your problem was solved using his solution :)

Comment: Gladly but I couldn't find where I can do that?

Comment: You should see the outline of a tick near barry's answer and you click once on it to mark it as accepted.